# Using external associated array in awk

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I've a bash script which create an associated array.
Then, I launch a awk command for parse the output of a grep command.
In my awk command, I want to make a print using the associated array but if I understand well, the awk can't access to it. So how can I do it ?

I just want to list for each equipement (1 file per equipement) each port where its speed is "10", "a-10", "100" or "a-100". In the output, I need the port (GiX/X/X), the VLAN, the speed and the full description

```
for entry in `ls TF5* | grep -v ".desc"`; do
    declare -A description

    while read line
    do
            if echo $line | grep "Gi" > /dev/null
            then
                    port=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
                    description[${port}]=$(echo "$line" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4-)
            fi
    done < $entry.desc

    grep " a-10 " $entry | awk '{printf ("a10:\t%s ;\t%s ;\t%s ;\n", $1, "$description[$1]", $4)}'
    ...
```

Input sample :
File TF5XXXXXX without .desc

```
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Gi1/0/1   *** SW1-BTB-XXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/4   XYZAB connected    trunk      a-full a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/5   YAZER connected    trunk      a-full 10 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/6   BLABL connected    trunk      a-full a-10 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/7   AHAHO connected    trunk      a-full 1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/8   XXXXX connected    trunk      a-full 100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/9   XXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
```

File TF5XXXXXX with .desc

```
Interface                      Status         Protocol Description
Vl1                            admin down     down
Vl101                          up             up
Fa0                            down           down
Gi1/0/1                        up             up       *** SW1-BTB-BALBLA ***
Gi1/0/2                        down           down
Gi1/0/3                        down           down     DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT
Gi1/0/4                        up             up       DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT
Gi1/0/5                        up             up       DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT
Gi1/0/6                        up             up       DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT
Gi1/0/7                        up             up       DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT
Gi1/0/8                        up             up       DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT
Gi1/0/9                        up             up       DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT
```

Output sample :

```
a-100 TAB Gi1/0/4 TAB  DESCRIPTION TAB VLAN
10 TAB Gi1/0/5 TAB  DESCRIPTION TAB VLAN
a-10 TAB Gi1/0/6 TAB  DESCRIPTION TAB VLAN
100 TAB Gi1/0/8 TAB  DESCRIPTION TAB VLAN
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: correct, awk is not shell. Get rid of your shell loops and just do whatever it is you're trying to do in awk. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice. post some sample input and expected output if you'd like help.

Comment: Don't parse `ls`. Use `for entry in TF5*; do [[ $f =~ .desc ]] && continue` instead.

Comment: I've added some input and what I want in the output.

Comment: @chepner, I'm not sure to understand the last part : 
`[[ $f =~ .desc ]] && continue`
I guess $f is in fact $entry, but why continue and why your test

Comment: That's the part that replaces `grep`. The pattern matches all files, and the test skips the ones that have .desc in the names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
for entry in TF5*.desc;do 
  awk 'NR==FNR{key=$1;$1=$2=$3="";a[key]=$0;next}
       $(NF-1)~/(a-)?10(0)?$/{print $(NF-1)"\t"$1"\t"a[$1]"\t"$4}' $entry ${entry%.desc}
done
```

Results:

```
a-100   Gi1/0/4    DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT  trunk
10  Gi1/0/5    DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT  trunk
a-10    Gi1/0/6    DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT  trunk
100 Gi1/0/8    DESCRIPTION CENSURED BUT I NEED TO CATCH IT  trunk
```

Comment: Thanks @klashxx
I got an error : 
`./script_countspeed_2.sh    awk: cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=TF5_MOBXXXXXXX FNR=1) fatal: attempt to access field -1`

Comment: Then  i guess that ``TAB`` is the field separator of your input files .. correct? @Rian

Comment: Nop, TAB have to be the output field seperator. But le FS of my input files is a space. But at the beginning of the files, there is some empty lines. @klashxx

Comment: the problem was my empty lines at the beginning .. @klashxx